# How to get column names of sql query when using bigquery API in c#

Tags: c#, sql, api, google-bigquery

Title says it all here is my code i cant find any way to do it
i can print rows and i have to specify the column names
but i cant find a way to get all the column names
does bigquery api not return column names with the results?

this is my code so far
How can i print all the column names?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> rows = new List<string>();
            string projectId = "project-id 123";
            var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM table";
            var res = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters: null);

            foreach (var row in res)
                Console.WriteLine(row["id"])
                //rows.Add(row["id"])
        }
```

Comment: I usually use a DataAdapter (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)  and fill a DataSet.  The column names can be obtains from the columns of the DataTable : string[] names = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
string[] columns = res.Keys.ToArray();
```

Comment: This will not work because `res` is query results (rows) and they cannot contain column names as keys

Answer (score 0):

You are itearating `BigQueryRow` items.

The BigQueryRow class contains a Table row that contains a ETag. ETag can be the column name.

The BigQueryRow class

[image]

The TableRow class

[image]

You must access to the ETags on each iteration.

Try this code

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
            string projectId = "project-id 123";
            var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM table";
            var res = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters: null);
            
            foreach (var row in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.RawRow.ETag);
            }
```